# how to calculate packet drop % for AWS NAT Gateway in New Relic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, newrelic, aws-nat-gateway, nrql

I'm trying to calculate the Packets Drop % in the new relic for AWS NAT Gateway
I'm able found out that Drop Percentage = (Number of Dropped Packets / Number of Transmitted Packets) * 100

i have the attribute for Packet Drop but i'm not able to understand what would be the total transmitted packets
i have the following attributes for the refrence
PacketsInFromDestination, PacketsInFromSource, PacketsOutToDestination, PacketsOutToSource
but i'm not able to understand which one if these would be the disired diviser to find out the percentage

you can check the its integration page for more details
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/amazon-integrations/aws-integrations-list/aws-nat-gateway-monitoring-integration/

i'm not able to understand which one if these would be the disired diviser to find out the percentage